# Show that solution to initial value problem is a solution to another differential equation

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, vectors

"A system of differential equations is given by $$\begin{bmatrix} x_1'(t) \\ x_2'(t) \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x_1(t) \\ x_2(t) \end{bmatrix}$$

1. **Give the complete solution to the system of differential equations and find the solution satisfying the inital value problem** $$\begin{bmatrix} x_1(0) \\ x_2(0) \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

So I have found the complete solution to be $$x(t)=c_1 \cdot e^{-t} \begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} + c_2 \cdot e^t \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$$ and the solution satifying the initial value problem to be $$-\frac{1}{2} \cdot e^{-t} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} + \frac{1}{2} \cdot e^t \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

2. **Another differential equation is given by** $$x''(t)=\sqrt{1+x'(t)^2}$$

**Show that the solution to $x_1(t)$ satisfying the initial value problem is a solution to this differential equation**

The solution to $x_1(t)$ is $x_1(t)=\frac{1}{2} \cdot e^{-t} + \frac{1}{2} \cdot e^t$

So, to show that this in in fact a solution to the differential equation I guess I should insert $x_1(t)$ in the differential equation.

We have $$x_1''(t)=\frac{1}{2} e^{-t} + \frac{1}{2} e^t$$ and $$x_1'(t)=- \frac{1}{2} e^{-t} + \frac{1}{2} e^t$$

Inserted into the differential equation $x''(t)=\sqrt{1+x'(t)^2}$ we get $$(\frac{1}{2} e^{-t}+\frac{1}{2} e^t)=\sqrt{1+(-\frac{1}{2} e^{-t}+\frac{1}{2} e^t)^2}$$

If we replace **t** with **0** we get $1=1$ which is obviously true, but is that a correct way to show that $x_1(t)$ is a solution to the differential equation?

Comment: Hint: Simplify the expression inside the root. What is $(e^t-e^{-t})^2$? Alternative hint: note that $x_1(t)=\cosh t$ ([properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function)).

Comment: @A.Γ. thanks for answering. So I can put $\frac{1}{2}$ outside the parenthesis and get $\sqrt{1 +\frac{1}{2}(e^{t}-e^{-t})^2}$. Does the parenthesis equal 0? I'm not really sure why...

Comment: If the parenthesis is zero then $x_1'(t)=0$. Does it look reasonable? It is hardly any mathematics involved in this simplification, just routine calculations. Try to rewrite the expression under the root in different forms to find out the simplest one.

Comment: @A.Γ.. I see, i does not make sense if $x_1'(t)=0$. I still can't seem to figure out how to simplify the root... Could you give a point in the right direction?

Comment: You can just square the equality to get rid of the root.

Comment: @A.Γ. Yep, I tried that. That gives me $$( \frac{1}{2} e^{-t} + \frac{1}{2} e^t)^2=1+( \frac{1}{2} e^t - \frac{1}{2} e^{-t})^2$$ That's where I'm stuck..

Comment: Use that $(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$.

Comment: @A.Γ. Finally, got it! $$(\frac{1}{2}e^{-t}+\frac{1}{2}e^t)^2=1+(\frac{1}{2}e^{t}-\frac{1}{2}e^{-t})^2 \Rightarrow (\frac{1}{2}e^{-t}+\frac{1}{2}e^t)^2-(\frac{1}{2}e^{t}-\frac{1}{2}e^{-t})^2=1 \Rightarrow \frac{1}{4}e^{2t}+\frac{1}{4}e^{-2t}+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4}e^{2t}-\frac{1}{4}e^{-2t}+\frac{1}{2}=1 \Rightarrow 1=1$$ Thanks for your patience!